# DEXClassLoader doesn't finish up

Tags: android, reflection, dalvik, dex

Have been trying to find any kind of info how to prevent or handle this weird behaviour with DEXLoader.

I'm loading external jar into my app but from time to time it doesn't finish, and I get no errors either.
The only thing I see in logcat is:

> D/dalvikvm(5764): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'test.jar'
>   (bootstrap=0) ---

The weird thing is that when I re-run my app and try to load again, sometimes it works (i get the --- END in logcat, but sometimes it just "freezes".

Any idea why and how to prevent that?

Here's a snippet of third attempt, which were successful

```
D/dalvikvm(1941): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'test.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
D/dalvikvm(1941): GC_CONCURRENT freed 473K, 13% free 10856K/12359K, paused 3ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(1966): DexOpt: load 38ms, verify+opt 192ms
D/dalvikvm(1941): GC_CONCURRENT freed 486K, 11% free 11045K/12359K, paused 3ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(1941): DexOpt: --- END 'test.jar' (success) ---
D/dalvikvm(1941): DEX prep '/mnt/sdcard/test.jar': unzip in 59ms, rewrite 379ms
```

Comment: That's quite interesting, i am having this issue form time to time which makes me guess it should be common behavior but searching for that behavior and finding "solution" seems to be nearly impossible. :(

Comment: If you have a rooted and relatively recent device, you can run `adb shell debuggerd -b <pid>`, where `<pid>` is the process ID of the stalled dexopt process.  What version of Android are you using?

Comment: Yeah i actually rooted the phone few days ago to remove pre-installed applications from Sony. the current Android running now on that phone is 4.0.4 (4.1.b.0.587)